# can someone change the gpt command so that it works off google bard instead of open ai

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

my open ai trail creds ended, i want to try and change it to google bard though, i am not using a dotenv file to hold the keys and im keeping them in the command file themself.if its possible can the cookie be kept inside this command file just to make it easier.

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require('openai');
const fs = require('fs');


const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: 's//'
});


const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);


module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('ama')
    .setDescription('ask me anything!')
    .addStringOption(option => option.setName('question').setDescription('type any question...(the more info the more accurate)').setRequired(true))
    .setDMPermission(false),
    async execute(interaction) {

      await interaction.deferReply();

      const question = interaction.options.getString('question');
      const data = {
        date: new Date().toLocaleDateString(),
        time: new Date().toLocaleTimeString(),
        prompt: question,
        username: interaction.user.username,
        userID: interaction.user.id,
        guildName: interaction.guild.name,
        guildID: interaction.guild.id, 
        channel: interaction.channel.id,
        channel:interaction.channel.name
    };
    const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data) + '\n';
    
    fs.appendFile('interactionData.json', jsonData, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return;
        }
        console.log('Interaction data saved to file');
    });
    try {
      const gptResponse = await openai.createCompletion({
        model: "text-davinci-003",
        temperature: 0.7,
        max_tokens: 2048,
        prompt: question,
      })

      console.log(gptResponse)
      //console.log(gptResponse.choices)
      //console.log(gptResponse.data)
      //console.log(gptResponse.data.choices)
      console.log(gptResponse.data.choices[0])

      const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setColor('Greyple')
      .setDescription(`${gptResponse.data.choices[0].text}`)
      
      //invite randomiser
      const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
      console.log(randomNumber)
if (randomNumber === 1) {
  const inviteLink = "https://discord.gg/UmGn6t6xAB";
  interaction.editReply({content:'join our server! https://discord.gg/UmGn6t6xAB',embeds: [embed]})
return;
}

      await interaction.editReply({ embeds: [embed]});
    
    }catch(e) {
      console.log(e)
      const errEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setColor('#696969')
      .setTitle('Error :redcross:')
      .setThumbnail('https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/oqVFIYggxfORW6MFwlFdWJQvSw5YuIGsZ6VdQ5FssQwY6qVaGvE7N4vMWm2N315ksqMas8MQ7kRfo_TI5ncgIbxtS9jBiO99xYTsUmQc0GmPaban1mGHJViBLNBdhRw2fuRSQfZqRu-EyOrKtTEfsScjD_3-hsFcVgKRTZ0uo28mLnGXZTs30SNX5fzbgpFhGO762BDwWuwhmdv5xSxSeWKtAayuHEcjOlsux7v3OLk7Wo9tEfYLlb-nvF2NTYb9IfTc2Y5KIUCtGB1LSi32ccjQk8-jg_RObyH1TIyTMhj4xk32ZVWF0bo0i4XU8sBB1oRnJBKPosNmnoRK3jZeGrJAhiKYqwukXQITk4ArMRIDACdHszAqXuKRmlg4_3r_Keln1jyWWTkAoPIPWz_broMQTnSMA96kY91b--SoGoqHCdW82aq7JQ41zVgUKJR-wHLB-P2wpsR1JjNZFMcca4AfaYCt673C5O2az2IIQXyVbH6h_GnvLA1Qkb2fktgYeeoOOTcVr4HhoqK5CQ1RNGBTNkUEdDqElS9BTpPFtnzToeDjX-jPkzdkwgWxara2_Gs5kAeL2a2NqnOcVio7JhQCGxgnFBcA_zhv7EZXdQdHyvEfCMnYgMD3pTu6vO9Yp9xkUDcmvlH1aPIloI2qsrKTWh7Yg1fk-UB3w8u_3ChUFkjsuoRzIFDtPaRyjjKMgPFlWSJJ1MzfeZ651YuFTAI4NXrr4YxfhVbX72hPfkup2XUEgw4J0pSxhiiLKHWv-TCmsdmyrH7A_WZv6ZfIUQw06_3PaDK_NdloIuAEDT5Na2DxxLkhqpNRXlJtZKRX6wBCtPJgAsBd2dTed_U8OmMSiTE7QFWNbiM5n3KNUW9WJGLJLqi1C9zC_DFtk9hYOnwFd9R5K-8vbfIVDIV68AdFQOXAVbJAr42dBkb716L4=s328-no?authuser=0')
      .addFields(
        { name: 'Error code:', value: e.response.status }
      )
      .setFooter({
        text: "AMA",
        iconURL: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/oqVFIYggxfORW6MFwlFdWJQvSw5YuIGsZ6VdQ5FssQwY6qVaGvE7N4vMWm2N315ksqMas8MQ7kRfo_TI5ncgIbxtS9jBiO99xYTsUmQc0GmPaban1mGHJViBLNBdhRw2fuRSQfZqRu-EyOrKtTEfsScjD_3-hsFcVgKRTZ0uo28mLnGXZTs30SNX5fzbgpFhGO762BDwWuwhmdv5xSxSeWKtAayuHEcjOlsux7v3OLk7Wo9tEfYLlb-nvF2NTYb9IfTc2Y5KIUCtGB1LSi32ccjQk8-jg_RObyH1TIyTMhj4xk32ZVWF0bo0i4XU8sBB1oRnJBKPosNmnoRK3jZeGrJAhiKYqwukXQITk4ArMRIDACdHszAqXuKRmlg4_3r_Keln1jyWWTkAoPIPWz_broMQTnSMA96kY91b--SoGoqHCdW82aq7JQ41zVgUKJR-wHLB-P2wpsR1JjNZFMcca4AfaYCt673C5O2az2IIQXyVbH6h_GnvLA1Qkb2fktgYeeoOOTcVr4HhoqK5CQ1RNGBTNkUEdDqElS9BTpPFtnzToeDjX-jPkzdkwgWxara2_Gs5kAeL2a2NqnOcVio7JhQCGxgnFBcA_zhv7EZXdQdHyvEfCMnYgMD3pTu6vO9Yp9xkUDcmvlH1aPIloI2qsrKTWh7Yg1fk-UB3w8u_3ChUFkjsuoRzIFDtPaRyjjKMgPFlWSJJ1MzfeZ651YuFTAI4NXrr4YxfhVbX72hPfkup2XUEgw4J0pSxhiiLKHWv-TCmsdmyrH7A_WZv6ZfIUQw06_3PaDK_NdloIuAEDT5Na2DxxLkhqpNRXlJtZKRX6wBCtPJgAsBd2dTed_U8OmMSiTE7QFWNbiM5n3KNUW9WJGLJLqi1C9zC_DFtk9hYOnwFd9R5K-8vbfIVDIV68AdFQOXAVbJAr42dBkb716L4=s328-no?authuser=0'
      });


    return await interaction.editReply({ embeds: [errEmbed], ephemeral: true })
      return await interaction.editReply({content: `Request failed with status code **${e.response.status}**`, ephemeral: true})
    }

  }
}
```

my friend and i tried but we couldn't get it to work